# Which HTML5 tag should I use to mark up an author’s name?

Tags: html, tags, blogs, semantic-markup

For example of a blog-post or article.

```
<article>
<h1>header<h1>
<time>09-02-2011</time>
<author>John</author>
My article....
</article>
```

The `author` tag doesn't exist though... So what is the commonly used HTML5 tag for authors?
Thanks.

(If there isn't, shouldn't there be one?)

Comment: `<cite>` maybe? I don't know lol. :P  Doesn't make very much of a difference in style though.

Comment: It's not about style. Technically, you can use a <p> to create a heading just by increasing the font size. But search engines won't understand it like that.

Comment: You are not allowed to use the `time` element like that. Since `dd-mm-yyy` isn't one of the recognised formats, you have to supply a machine-readable version (in one of the recognised formats) in a `datetime` attribute of the `time` element. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/single-page.html#the-time-element

Comment: There's a [better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290504/which-html5-tag-should-i-use-to-mark-up-an-author-s-name/7290744#7290744) now than the accepted (robertc's) one.

Answer (score 137):

Both [`rel="author"`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#link-type-author) and [`<address>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-address-element) are designed for this exact purpose. Both are supported in HTML5. The spec tells us that [`rel="author"`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#link-type-author) can be used on [`<link>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-link-element) `<a>`, and `<area>` elements. Google also [recommends](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1408986) its [usage](http://www.blindfiveyearold.com/how-to-implement-rel-author). Combining use of `<address>` and `rel="author"` seems optimal. HTML5 best affords wrapping [`<article>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-article-element) headlines and bylines info in a `<header>` like so:

```
<article>
    <header>
        <h1 class="headline">Headline</h1>
        <div class="byline">
            <address class="author">By <a rel="author" href="/author/john-doe">John Doe</a></address> 
            on <time pubdate datetime="2011-08-28" title="August 28th, 2011">8/28/11</time>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="article-content">
    ...
    </div>
</article>
```

- The `pubdate` attribute indicates that that is the published date.
- The `title` attributes are optional flyovers.
- The byline info can alternatively be wrapped in a [`<footer>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-footer-element) within an [`<article>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-article-element)

If you want to add the **[hcard microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard)**, then I would do so like this:

```
<article>
    <header>
        <h1 class="headline">Headline</h1>
        <div class="byline vcard">
            <address class="author">By <a rel="author" class="url fn n" href="/author/john-doe">John Doe</a></address> 
            on <time pubdate datetime="2011-08-28" title="August 28th, 2011">on 8/28/11</time>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="article-content">
    ...
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Shouldn't "By " precede the <address> tag? It's not actually a part of the address.

Comment: @aridlehoover Either seems correct according to http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-address-element - If outside, use `.byline address { display:inline; font-style:inherit }` to override the `block` default in browsers.

Comment: @aridlehoover I also think that `<dl>` is viable. See the byline markup in the source of http://demo.actiontheme.com/sample-page/ for example.

Comment: Since the `pubdate` attribute is gone from both the WHATWG and W3C specs, as  Bruce Lawson writes [here](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/best-of-time/), I suggest you to remove it from your answer.

Answer (score 52):

HTML5 has an [author link type](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#link-type-author):

```
<a href="http://johnsplace.com" rel="author">John</a>
```

The weakness here is that it needs to be on some sort of link, but if you have that there's a [long discussion of alternatives here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-simplequiz-5-urls-of-commenters/).  If you don't have a link, then just use a class attribute, that's what it's for:

```
<span class="author">John</span>
```

Comment: nice, thanks for the link... I guess you could do it without the href? like `<a rel='author'>John</a> ... though semantically won't make that much sense...

Comment: @Quang Yes, I think a link type without an actual link would defeat the purpose of trying to mark it up semantically.

Comment: @Quang: the `rel` attribute is there to describe what the link’s destination is. If the link has no destination, `rel` is meaningless.

Comment: You might also want to look at http://schema.org/ for ways of expressing this type of information.

Comment: Why not `<cite>John</cite>`?

Comment: @jdh8 Because John is not [the title of a work](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element)

Comment: @robertc Oh, I see. It's only available in [HTML 5.1 Nightly](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element).

Comment: This answer just isn't the best any longer. [Google no longer supports `rel="author"`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?rd=1), and as [ryanve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290504/which-html5-tag-should-i-use-to-mark-up-an-author-s-name/7295013#7295013) and Jason mention, the `address` tag was explicitly design for expressing authorship as well.

Comment: "use a class attribute, that's what it's for" -- that's wrong! The class attribute is a selector for CSS and JavaScript, it doesn't have any semantic meaning in HTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class

Comment: @amiuhle "Though the specification doesn't put requirements on the name of classes, web developers are encouraged to use names that describe the semantic purpose of the element, rather to the presentation of the element..."

Answer (score 23):

According to the HTML5 spec, you probably want `address`.

> The address element represents the contact information for its
>   nearest article or body element ancestor.

The spec further references `address` in respect to authors here

**Under 4.4.4**

> Author information associated with an article element (q.v. the
>   address element) does not apply to nested article elements.

**Under 4.4.9**

> Contact information for the author or editor of a section belongs in
>   an address element, possibly itself inside a footer.

All of which makes it seems that `address` is the best tag for this info.

That said, you could also give your `address` a `rel` or `class` of `author`.

```
<address class="author">Jason Gennaro</address>
```

Read more: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#the-address-element

Comment: Thanks Jason, do you know what "q.v." means? Under >4.4.4
>Author information associated with an article element (q.v. the address element) does not apply to nested article elements.

Comment: @QuangVan - (wait, your initials are ... q.v. hmm) - q.v. means "quod vide" or "on this (matter) go see" - son on the matter of "q.v." go see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25252/how-does-one-correctly-use-q-v (q.v.) haha

Comment: @JasonGennaro haha nanos gigantum humeris insidentes!

Comment: lol, took me a while to figure out what these comments were referring to... Thanks for the Latin lession :)

Answer (score 17):

In HTML5 we can use some semantic labels that help organize the information regarding your type of content, but additional and related to the subject you can check [schema.org](https://schema.org). It is an initiative of Google, Bing and Yahoo that aims to help search engines to better understand websites through microdata attributes. Your post could look like this:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<header>
  <h1 itemprop="headline">header</h1>
  <time itemprop="dateCreated datePublished">09-02-2011</time>
  <div itemprop="author publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <p>
        <img itemprop="image logo" src="..."/>
        <span itemprop="name">John</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</header>
<section itemprop="articleBody" >
    My article....
    <img itemprop="image" src="..."/>
</section>
</article>
```

Comment: Definitely the most accurate answer for 2019.

Comment: Note that schema.org is not part of HTML5. It is a separate specification.

Comment: Also note that Google recommends to always use JSON-LD in favor of microdata attributes: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#markup-formats-and-placement

Answer (score 11):

Google support for rel="author" [is deprecated](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?rd=1):

> "Authorship markup is no longer supported in web search."

**Use a Description List (Definition List in HTML 4.01)  element.**

From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element):

> The dl element represents an association list consisting of zero or more name-value groups (a description list). A name-value group consists of one or more names (dt elements) followed by one or more values (dd elements), ignoring any nodes other than dt and dd elements. Within a single dl element, there should not be more than one dt element for each name.
>
> Name-value groups may be terms and definitions, metadata topics and values, questions and answers, or any other groups of name-value data.

Authorship and other article meta information fits perfectly into this key:value pair structure:

- who is the author
- date the article published
- site structure under which the article is organized (category/tag: string/arrays)
- etc.

An opinionated example:

```
<article>
  <header>
    <h1>Article Title</h1>
    <p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
    <dl class="dateline">
      <dt>Author:</dt>
      <dd>Remy Schrader</dd>
      <dt>All posts by author:</dt>
      <dd><a href="http://www.blog.net/authors/remy-schrader/">Link</a></dd>
      <dt>Contact:</dt>
      <dd><a mailto="remy@blog.net"><img src="email-sprite.png"></a></dd>
    </dl>
  </header>
  <section class="content">
    <!-- article content goes here -->
  </section>
</article>
```

As you can see when using the `<dl>` element for article meta information, we are free to wrap `<address>`, `<a>` and even `<img>` tags in `<dt>` and/or `<dd>` tags according to **the nature of the content and it's intended function**.
The `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags are free to do their job -- semantically -- conveying information about the parent `<article>`; `<a>`, `<img>` and `<address>` are similarly free to do their job -- again, semantically -- conveying information regarding where to find related content, non-verbal visual presentation, and contact details for authoritative parties, respectively.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
<meta name="author" content="John Doe">
```

in the header as per the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names).

Answer (score 2):

If you were including contact details for the author, then the `<address>` tag is appropriate:

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-address-element.html#the-address-element

But if it’s literally just the author’s name, there isn’t a specific tag for that. HTML doesn’t include much related to people.

Answer (score 2):

How about [microdata](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#examples-1):

```
<article>
<h1>header<h1>
<time>09-02-2011</time>
<div id="john" itemscope itemtype="http://microformats.org/profile/hcard">
 <h2 itemprop="fn">
  <span itemprop="n" itemscope>
   <span itemprop="given-name">John</span>
  </span>
 </h2>
</div>
My article....
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use meta tag for this purpose, as follows:

```html
<head>
<meta name="author" content="red bot">
</head>
```