# HTML5 author tag

Tags: html, tags, author

It's a really easy question but is it true the html tag  isn't really existing or not released yet? So to do it right the notation will be  ? I can't find documentation about the 'author' tag as well.

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5

```
<a href="http://example.com" rel="author">Sri</a>
```

Refer [Which HTML5 tag should I use to mark up an author’s name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290504/which-html5-tag-should-i-use-to-mark-up-an-authors-name)